# Grouping data series in scatter chart

Tags: excel, pivot, excel-2010, scatter-plot

I have a big data set with `50-60` data series in it which is plotted on a scatter graph (let's assume it is similar to the plot of velocity and time for different car models). Is it possible to group them by some category (for example car companies) so that I can filter and view related ones at once?

I can not create a pivot table from the chart unfortunately because the data acquisition frequency of parameters are different and series cannot be combined.
Thanks for the answers beforehand!